# read microsoft word document in java

Tags: java, file-handling

is there a simple way of reading a microsoft word document in java without using Apache POI package?

Or what are other alternative to achieving the same without using Apache POI package?

Comment: What do you mean by "reading"? Word documents from recent versions of MS Office are zip-compatible packages containing XML documents corresponding to the text-based content of the document - you can read those using Java's ZIP and XML libraries ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731948/java-library-for-reading-word-documents

Comment: Here is a good link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383473/read-microsoft-word-document-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383473/read-microsoft-word-document-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a commercial alternative which is pretty easy-to-use but commercial - [Aspose](https://www.aspose.com/products/words)

Answer (score 1):

[Using Java to Crack Office 2007](http://www.infoq.com/articles/cracking-office-2007-with-java) might help.

Answer (score 0):

java docx ? http://www.javadocx.com/ it's not much for reading, but for generating dynamic output.

Comment: Does that pull from a docx file too?

Comment: yeah. docx is an archive, if you extract it you can see many files, and somewhere will be an xml .. I didn't used it, just read a little about it. sorry

Comment: Oh, I've dug deep into docx files before, I was just wondering if that library could read them in addition to writing them.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. If it is a WordML file, you can unzip it and then manually extract the data from the XML files inside, but trust me, it is not a pleasant process. When we tried to do it at my company we had hoped to be able to leverage some of the OOo libraries to clean up the documents and, well, it didn't work too well.